# What is incorrect about this simple query?

Tags: sql-server

```
select ReplenishDate,Amount
from vw_replenishmentData
where (select max(ReplenishDate) from vw_replenishmentData)
```

Comment: ` where (select max(ReplenishDate) from vw_replenishmentData)` what? How do you interpret this as a statement in English?

Comment: where ReplenishDate = (select max(ReplenishDate) from vw_replenishmentData)

Answer (score 1):

Your where statement is invalid, try something like this:

```
select ReplenishDate,Amount 
from 
vw_replenishmentData 
where ReplenishDate= (select max(ReplenishDate) maxDate from vw_replenishmentData)
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you need to use column name in where to filter your result some thing like  `.. where  columnname = (select max(...`

Instead of using `subquery` use `Top 1 with Ties`.

```
select Top 1 with ties ReplenishDate,Amount
from vw_replenishmentData
order by ReplenishDate desc
```